# why is my code going really slow, it wasn't the other day ad now it runs at a ridiculously slow pace

Tags: python, pygame, replit

why is my code going really slow, it wasn't the other day ad now it runs at a ridiculously slow pace.

its part of my game for college and no one can figure out why its so slow and i really dont want to restart. what i cant figure out is why its such a slow pace. i dont really understand code but ive tried to go through to get t fixed but no matter what i do to no avail and it still wont work plz help

```
import random
from time import sleep
import time
import pygame


seconds = 0

class CarRacing:
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.display_width = 800
        self.display_height = 600
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.white = (255, 255, 255)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.gameDisplay = None


        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.crashed = False

        self.carImg = pygame.image.load('img/bojo.png')
        self.car_x_coordinate = (self.display_width * 0.45)
        self.car_y_coordinate = (self.display_height * 0.8)
        self.car_width = 49

        # enemy_car
        self.enemy_car = pygame.image.load('img/Coal_JE1.png')
        self.enemy_car_startx = random.randrange(310, 450)
        self.enemy_car_starty = 600
        self.enemy_car_speed = 5
        self.enemy_car_width = 10
        self.enemy_car_height = 1

        # Background

        self.bgImg1 = pygame.image.load("img/Grassy background.png")
        self.bgImg1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.bgImg1, (800,600))
        self.bg1_x1 = (self.display_width/2) - 425
        self.bg1_x2 = (self.display_width/2) - 425
        print (str(self.bg1_x1), str(self.bg1_x2))
        self.bg1_y1 = 0
        self.bg1_y2 = -600
 
        self.bg_speed = 3
        self.count = 0
          

    def car(self, car_x_coordinate, car_y_coordinate):
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.carImg, (car_x_coordinate, car_y_coordinate))

    def racing_window(self):
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((self.display_width, self.display_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Car Race --  :))')
        self.run_car()

    def run_car(self):
        
        while not self.crashed:
            seconds = 0
            seconds +=1
            time.sleep(1)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.crashed = True
                # print(event)

                if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                        self.car_x_coordinate -= 50
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        self.car_x_coordinate += 50

            self.gameDisplay.fill(self.black)


            self.back_ground_raod1()

  


            self.run_enemy_car(self.enemy_car_startx, self.enemy_car_starty)
            self.enemy_car_starty += self.enemy_car_speed

            if self.enemy_car_starty > self.display_height:
                self.enemy_car_starty = 0 - self.enemy_car_height
                self.enemy_car_startx = random.randrange(310, 450)
 # speed values below
            self.car(self.car_x_coordinate, self.car_y_coordinate)
            self.highscore(self.count)
            self.count += 0
            if (self.count % 100 == 0):
                self.enemy_car_speed += 1
                self.bg_speed += -0

            if self.car_y_coordinate < (self.enemy_car_starty + self.enemy_car_height):
                if self.car_x_coordinate > self.enemy_car_startx and self.car_x_coordinate < self.enemy_car_startx + self.enemy_car_width or self.car_x_coordinate + self.car_width > self.enemy_car_startx and self.car_x_coordinate + self.car_width < self.enemy_car_startx + self.enemy_car_width:
                    self.crashed = True
                    self.display_message("Your the epitome of failure !!!")

            if self.car_x_coordinate < 250 or self.car_x_coordinate > 460:
                self.crashed = True
                self.display_message("You suck!!!")

            pygame.display.update(
            )

            self.clock.tick(60)

    def display_message(self, msg):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72, True)
        text = font.render(msg, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (400 - text.get_width() // 2, 240 - text.get_height() // 2))
        self.display_credit()
        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(60)
        sleep(1)
        car_racing.initialize()
        car_racing.racing_window()

    def back_ground_raod1(self):
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.bgImg1, (self.bg1_x1, self.bg1_y1))
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.bgImg1, (self.bg1_x2, self.bg1_y2))

        self.bg1_y1 += self.bg_speed
        self.bg1_y2 += self.bg_speed

        if self.bg1_y1 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg1_y1 = -600

        if self.bg1_y2 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg1_y2 = -600
          


    def run_enemy_car(self, thingx, thingy):
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.enemy_car, (thingx, thingy))

    def highscore(self, count):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("JakeConsole", 20)
        text = font.render("Score : " + str(count), True, self.white)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

    def display_credit(self):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("JakeConsole", 14)
        text = font.render("Thanks to me,", True, self.white)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (600, 520))
        text = font.render("Jake Edge", True, self.white)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (600, 540))
        text = font.render("B00", True, self.white)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (600, 560))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    car_racing = CarRacing()
    car_racing.racing_window()
    #audio.play_file('audio/mp3')
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because of the **time.sleep(1)** in the **run_car()**-method?

Looks like it sleeps for 1 second every loop

Comment: thank you tis working now :)